# Orchard widgets triggered more than once

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, widget, orchardcms

I am calling a controller action from a widget shape.
The problem that I am facing is that the widget is being triggered more than once which is causing my controller action to fire for than once.

Does anyone has any idea why widget is being triggered more than once?

The layer rule that is assigned for the widget only allows the widget to be displayed for 2 urls using an 'Or' condition.

Comment: please add some code and we will be able to help

Comment: What do you mean by "trigger"? Where is the code that gets called multiple times? Why are you calling into a controller action, instead of moving the code from this action into a service class that you can call from both places?